# Why does AppCache not work on IE11 mobile?

Tags: indexeddb, nokia, offline-caching, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I have a website which utilises App Cache and IndexedDb in a secure context (ie https://) to enable use offline. This works fine for most of the devices I have tested on. However on a Nokia Lumia 920 using IE11 mobile (which [does support app cache](https://caniuse.com/#search=app%20cache)), I get an error when trying to access the website offline after an initial load online to populate the cache.

The error is: `Cannot find server or DNS error`.

Since the browser does apparently support App Cache, I do not understand why this error occurs on this device. On all other devices I have tested on it works fine. Including IE11 on Windows desktop.

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

[image: Offline error]

I am aware that the device and AppCache itself are deprecated.